# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Tried searching around and couldn't find a direct answer to my problem, as all other codes out there appear to be doing what I'm doing. I'm working on a shell scripting exercise to calculate averages for a class, and I've made it to this point using our reference scripts, however I'm getting errors about the syntax (error at bottom of code)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

avg=0
temp_total=0
number_of_args=$#

# First see the sufficient cmd args
if [ $# -lt 2 ] ; then
        echo -e "Oops! I need at least 2 command line args to calculate an average\n"
        echo -e "Syntax: $0: number1 number2 ... numberN\n"
        echo -e "Example:$0 5 4\n\t$0 56 66 34"
        exit 1
fi

# now calculate the average of the numbers given on command line as cmd args for i in $*
do
     # addition of all the numbers on cmd args
        temp_total='expr $temp_total + $i '
done

avg='expr $temp_total / $number_of_args '
echo "The average of all the numbers is $avg"
```

So, the error I'm getting is

```
./avg.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./avg.sh: line 16: `do'
```

I can't find anything particularly wrong around that area, so I was hoping someone could help me out! Thanks!

edit: In particular, I've tried removing the comments on the off chance that they were causing issues, to no avail. I re-typed the section as well. I also tried finding different ways to handle that portion, but most averaging scripts seem to handle it in a very similar fashion, so I'm at a loss!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message complains about an unexpected `do` because you used it wrong: `do` is a reserved word used in `for`, `case`, `while` and `until` loops. As the preceding comment ends with `for i in $*` I assume you just forgot to add a line break there:

```bsh
# now calculate the average of the numbers given on command line as cmd args
for i in $*
do
  # addition of all the numbers on cmd args
  temp_total='expr $temp_total + $1 '
done
```

`man bash`/SHELL GRAMMAR/Compound Commands explains how to build `for` and other loops. If you simply want to loop over every argument `bash` also supports a short form, I'll combine it with [`bash` Arithmetic Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) here:

```bsh
# now calculate the average of the numbers given on command line as cmd args
for i
do
  # addition of all the numbers on cmd args
  temp_total=$((temp_total+i))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error from non-breaking spaces at the *start* of each line (happened to me when I copied code out of a Word document that used tabs and pasted it into Mac Notes to edit).